# Prove $(c-s)*P (Y \ge s) \ge EY − s$ for a random variable Y with y ∈ [0, c]

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expectation

Assume Y is a random value s.t. the RV takes value from the range [0, c] and for all s ∈ [0, c] prove the following: 
$$(c-s)*P (Y \ge s) \ge E(Y) − s$$

I tried to rewrite $P (Y \ge s)=1-\int f_ydy$ and then $EY=\int S_y dy$ Sy being the survivor function. Am I on the right track because I cant seem to progress here from here ( i tried multiple transformations but didnt workout.)

Comment: The inequality is equivalent to $E[(c-s)\mathbf{1}_{Y\geq s}] \geq E[Y - s]$. Can you continue?

Comment: do i need to use any theorem? btw it is E(Y)-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not difficult to verify that for every $y\in[0,c]$  we have:$$(c-s)1_{[s,\infty)}(y)\geq y-s$$

Since $Y\in[0,c]$ a.s. we are allowed to conclude that:$$(c-s)1_{[s,\infty)}(Y)\geq Y-s\quad \text{ a.s.}$$

From this it follows directly that:$$(c-s)\mathsf P(Y\geq s)=(c-s)\mathsf E1_{[s,\infty)}(Y)=\mathsf E(c-s)1_{[s,\infty)}(Y)\geq\mathsf E(Y-s)=\mathsf EY-s$$

Comment: can you give hints on how to verity the first one?; so if y<s, then y-s is negative while right side is positive? and if y>s, then c-s>y-s?

Comment: $y\in[0,c]$ so $c\geq y$ and consequently $c-s\geq y-s$